# Example code not working with DirectShow

Tags: c++, video, directshow, playback, avi

that's my problem: I'm trying to create a game for a school project and I created a video for it, so I googled a little bit and discovered that DirectShow provides some method to play .avi files, so I created a new project and pasted the example code I found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389098(v=vs.85).aspx), but this won't work because it throws an exception on &pEvent, &pControl and pGraph. The exception reports: Access violation reading location 0x04186000. How could I solve this problem? (I'm a very newbie with DirectShow so I'm sorry for my ignorance).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe i'm changing the issue but you may prefer opencv for reading videos. http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html

Comment: @seleciii44: The fact is that I'm not trying to capture a video, I just need to play it inside my WIN32 form. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: You should start by running it in debug mode and figuring out where exactly the access violation happens.

Comment: I eventually think I solved my problem, my codec wasn't working for that video, I tried with another one and worked fine. Thanks anyway.